# Upload doesn't do anything when I hit the upload button

Tags: php, file-upload, intranet

This is my first question here, I hope I can explain my problem. I have PHP code where I want to upload a PDF file and select a date, then upload it to a folder in my project called "pdfs". Then I want to download it but only until the date I chose at the upload is reached.

My upload doesn't work and I don't know why, here is my code:

````
<?php
    include_once 'headeradmin.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styleUpload.css">
        <title>Umleitung hochladen</title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <form action="umleitungen.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <h3>Umleitungen hochladen</h3>
                    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" accept="application/pdf"><br>
                    <p> Datum: <input type="date" name="ablaufdatum"></p> <br>
                    <button type="submit" name="save">Hochladen</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html> 

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'], $_POST['ablaufdatum']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'])) {
    $date = strtotime($_POST['ablaufdatum']);
    if (false === $date) {
        return;
    }
    $mimeType = mime_content_type($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
    $allowedFileTypes = ['application/pdf'];
    if (!in_array($mimeType, $allowedFileTypes, true)) {
        return;
    }
    $destination = 'pdfs/' . date('Y-m-d', $date) . '_' . time() . '.pdf';
    if (!file_exists($destination)) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $destination)) {
            echo 'Supi :)';
        } else {
            echo 'Upload fehlgeschlagen :/';
        }
    }
}

include_once 'footer.php';```
````

Comment: I think that your script never enter to the "if" section, because the condition is never true, you should change the isset condition from `submit` to "fileToUpload" or delete `submit` (there's no POST param with "submit" name, this is the "submit event").

Answer (score 0):

Check that the web server has permissions to write to the "pdfs/" directory.

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer, I work on my local server but I don't know how to check that, do you have any tips for me?

Comment: What OS / environment are you running your web server as?

Comment: Im using MacOS and Im using xampp for my localserver

Comment: I checked that my local Webserver has the permissions to write in this folder and it actually can.